# Flink state backend is not able to recover the taskmanager after failure

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to flink i am implementing a pattern identification module(not using CEP to implement pattern matching) which will read the stream of json from a EventHub topic and push to another Event Hub topic if pattern is matched. My module functionality is like below

1. Receive JSON payloads from Eventhub topic
2. I am using a RichSourceFunction which will read the patterns from API and send to Broadcast stream
3. I am using Flink BroadcastProcessFunction to process the data against list of patterns available in broadcast state and i am not using keyed stream or any states in my program since there no scope for states i just need to check certain values are present or not in the JSON .
4. I read that flink maintain states internally even no states are implemented explicitly
5. Below are setting for checkpointing and i receive around 1 million payloads every hour on an average some times it will be more also

   ```
    env.enableCheckpointing(interval);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    StateBackend stateBackend = new RocksDBStateBackend(incrementalCheckpointPath, true);
    env.setStateBackend(stateBackend);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointInterval(12000);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(1000);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(120000);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
   ```

But when task manager fails it is trying to restore state from statebackend i am using RocksDB as my statebacked but it is failing with below error. I am using Flink 1.10.0 version and Java 1.8

```
05:39:14.260 [Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (5/12)] WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure cisco - Exception while restoring operator state backend for StreamSource_1171dea6747ab509fdaefbe74f7195af_(5/12) from alternative (1/1), will retry while more alternatives are available.
org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Failed when trying to restore operator state backend
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:86) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createOperatorStateBackend(RocksDBStateBackend.java:565) ~[flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$operatorStateBackend$0(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:243) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.operatorStateBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:252) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:139) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:255) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeStateAndOpen(StreamTask.java:1006) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:454) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:449) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:461) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707) [flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532) [flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.read(LocalDataInputStream.java:68) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FSDataInputStreamWrapper.read(FSDataInputStreamWrapper.java:51) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:389) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.flink.util.LinkedOptionalMapSerializer.readOptionalMap(LinkedOptionalMapSerializer.java:86) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshotData.readDefaultKryoSerializerClasses(KryoSerializerSnapshotData.java:208) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshotData.createFrom(KryoSerializerSnapshotData.java:72) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshot.readSnapshot(KryoSerializerSnapshot.java:77) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:174) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.readNestedSerializerSnapshots(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:182) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.readSnapshot(CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.java:149) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:174) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.deserializeV2(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:179) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.read(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:150) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.readSerializerSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:76) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.metainfo.StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters$CurrentReaderImpl.readStateMetaInfoSnapshot(StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters.java:219) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.OperatorBackendSerializationProxy.read(OperatorBackendSerializationProxy.java:119) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.OperatorStateRestoreOperation.restore(OperatorStateRestoreOperation.java:83) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:83) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        ... 15 more
05:39:14.261 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor cisco - Un-registering task and sending final execution state CANCELED to JobManager for task Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (5/12) 0b418e2ffcd028a58f39029d3f8be08e.
05:39:14.261 [Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (3/12)] WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure cisco - Exception while restoring operator state backend for StreamSource_1171dea6747ab509fdaefbe74f7195af_(3/12) from alternative (1/1), will retry while more alternatives are available.
org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Failed when trying to restore operator state backend
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:86) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createOperatorStateBackend(RocksDBStateBackend.java:565) ~[flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$operatorStateBackend$0(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:243) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.operatorStateBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:252) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:139) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:255) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeStateAndOpen(StreamTask.java:1006) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:454) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:449) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:461) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707) [flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532) [flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.read(LocalDataInputStream.java:68) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FSDataInputStreamWrapper.read(FSDataInputStreamWrapper.java:51) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:389) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.flink.util.LinkedOptionalMapSerializer.readOptionalMap(LinkedOptionalMapSerializer.java:86) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshotData.readDefaultKryoSerializerClasses(KryoSerializerSnapshotData.java:208) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshotData.createFrom(KryoSerializerSnapshotData.java:72) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshot.readSnapshot(KryoSerializerSnapshot.java:77) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:174) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.readNestedSerializerSnapshots(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:182) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.readSnapshot(CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.java:149) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:174) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.deserializeV2(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:179) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.read(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:150) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.readSerializerSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:76) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.metainfo.StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters$CurrentReaderImpl.readStateMetaInfoSnapshot(StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters.java:219) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.OperatorBackendSerializationProxy.read(OperatorBackendSerializationProxy.java:119) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.OperatorStateRestoreOperation.restore(OperatorStateRestoreOperation.java:83) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:83) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        ... 15 more
05:39:14.262 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor cisco - Un-registering task and sending final execution state CANCELED to JobManager for task Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (3/12) a973d1d62f5086d1126d83d81278cc0a.
05:39:14.283 [Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/12)] WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure cisco - Exception while restoring operator state backend for StreamSource_1171dea6747ab509fdaefbe74f7195af_(1/12) from alternative (1/1), will retry while more alternatives are available.
org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Failed when trying to restore operator state backend
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:86) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createOperatorStateBackend(RocksDBStateBackend.java:565) ~[flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$operatorStateBackend$0(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:243) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.operatorStateBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:252) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:139) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:255) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeStateAndOpen(StreamTask.java:1006) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:454) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:449) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:461) [flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707) [flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532) [flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.read(LocalDataInputStream.java:68) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FSDataInputStreamWrapper.read(FSDataInputStreamWrapper.java:51) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:389) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:165) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.readNestedSerializerSnapshots(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:182) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.readSnapshot(CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.java:149) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:174) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.deserializeV2(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:179) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.read(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:150) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.readSerializerSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:76) ~[flink-core-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.metainfo.StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters$CurrentReaderImpl.readStateMetaInfoSnapshot(StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters.java:219) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.OperatorBackendSerializationProxy.read(OperatorBackendSerializationProxy.java:119) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.OperatorStateRestoreOperation.restore(OperatorStateRestoreOperation.java:83) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:83) ~[flink-runtime_2.12-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
        ... 15 more
05:39:14.283 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor cisco - Un-registering task and sending final execution state CANCELED to JobManager for task Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/12) c1a83f3812be2a4099737d6eee5b41d0.
05:39:14.441 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor cisco - Un-registering task and sending final execution state CANCELED to JobManager for task Sink: Cassandra Sink (1/4) caadf9ad0d011d308659cf47a3b74cc4.
05:40:36.616 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.slot.TaskSlotTableImpl cisco - Free slot TaskSlot(index:2, state:ACTIVE, resource profile: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1.0000000000000000, taskHeapMemory=85.333mb (89478482 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=136.533mb (143165578 bytes), networkMemory=34.133mb (35791394 bytes)}, allocationId: f5741b19f3f1281ae65d67994dba045b, jobId: a0d922bbf1c20ed9417415827c32e1a3).
05:40:36.617 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.slot.TaskSlotTableImpl cisco - Free slot TaskSlot(index:0, state:ACTIVE, resource profile: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1.0000000000000000, taskHeapMemory=85.333mb (89478482 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=136.533mb (143165578 bytes), networkMemory=34.133mb (35791394 bytes)}, allocationId: 5a92c83b6a105b726105cb0432980be6, jobId: a0d922bbf1c20ed9417415827c32e1a3).
05:40:36.618 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.slot.TaskSlotTableImpl cisco - Free slot TaskSlot(index:1, state:ACTIVE, resource profile: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1.0000000000000000, taskHeapMemory=85.333mb (89478482 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=136.533mb (143165578 bytes), networkMemory=34.133mb (35791394 bytes)}, allocationId: dd952690f30c88860b451b1ce4e2fc6d, jobId: a0d922bbf1c20ed9417415827c32e1a3).
05:40:36.618 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.JobLeaderService cisco - Remove job a0d922bbf1c20ed9417415827c32e1a3 from job leader monitoring.
05:40:36.618 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-95] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor cisco - Close JobManager connection for job a0d922bbf1c20ed9417415827c32e1a3.
05:40:36.621 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-110] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor cisco - Close JobManager connection for job a0d922bbf1c20ed9417415827c32e1a3.
05:40:36.621 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-110] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.JobLeaderService cisco - Cannot reconnect to job a0d922bbf1c20ed9417415827c32e1a3 because it is not registered.
```

Please help me in resolving the issue if i am doing any wrong and if needed any information please let me know.

Below is the code of BroadcastProcess Function and Cassandra Sink which i am using to persist the states of incoming signal for audit purpose

```
================================Source Function To Read Patterns from API Call=================================================
public class PatternSource extends RichSourceFunction<Map<String, Map<String, Pattern>>> {
    private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Map<String, Map<String, Pattern>>> ctx) throws Exception {
        String patternUrl =
                getRuntimeContext().getExecutionConfig().getGlobalJobParameters();
        Map<String, Map<String, Pattern>> patterns = getPatternData(patternUrl);
        ctx.collect(patterns);
        while (isRunning) {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
    
=================================================================================================================================


====================================================BroadcastProcessFunction Class================================================

public static final MapStateDescriptor<String, Map<String, String>> patternPatternDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor("PatternPatternDescriptor", 
BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, new MapTypeInfo(String.class, Pattern.class));

public class PatternDetection extends BroadcastProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, InputSignal>, Tuple2<String, Map<String, Pattern>>, Tuple2<String, InputSignal>> {

    public void processElement(Tuple2<String, InputSignal> InputSignal, BroadcastProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, InputSignal>, Tuple2<String, Map<String, Pattern>>, Tuple2<String, InputSignal>>.ReadOnlyContext ctx, Collector<Tuple2<String, InputSignal>> out) throws Exception {
            InputSignal signal = (InputSignal)InputSignal.f1;
            JSONObject InputSignalPayLoad = new JSONObject(signal.getSignalPayload());
            HashMap<String, InputSignal> finalOutput = new HashMap();
            String sourceName = ((InputSignal)InputSignal.f1).getSignalHeader().getSignalSource().toUpperCase();
            Map<String, Pattern> patternList = ctx.getBroadcastState(patternPatternDescriptor).get(sourceName);
    
            String patternName = Pattern.getPatternName();
            String patternDefinition = Pattern.getPatternDefinition();

            /*Implemented my custom JSON data matched*/
            Matcher<?> jsonMatcher = this.buildMatcher(patternDefinition);
            if (jsonMatcher != null && jsonMatcher.matches(Arrays.asList(InputSignalPayLoad))) {
                ctx.output(validSignalOutput, InputSignalPayLoad);
            }
        } 
    }
    
    public void processBroadcastElement(Tuple2<String, Map<String, Pattern>> patternCondition, BroadcastProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, InputSignal>, Tuple2<String, Map<String, Pattern>>, Tuple2<String, InputSignal>>.Context ctx, Collector<Tuple2<String, InputSignal>> out) throws Exception {
            String signalSource = ((String)patternCondition.f0).toUpperCase();
            BroadcastState<String, Map<String, Pattern>> state = ctx.getBroadcastState(patternPatternDescriptor);
            Map<String, Pattern> patterns = ctx.getBroadcastState(patternPatternDescriptor).get(signalSource);
    }
}

======================================================================================================================================



====================================================Cassandra Sink====================================================================

    public static void createInputSignalSink(DataStream<InputSignalSignalHistory> dataStream, Properties properties, int parallelism) {
        try {
            log.info(LogMessageBuilder.buildLogMessage("Inserting InputSignal signal history to cassandra database"));
            CassandraSink.addSink(dataStream).setClusterBuilder(buildClusterBuilder(properties)).setMapperOptions(() -> {
                return new Option[]{Option.saveNullFields(true)};
            }).build().setParallelism(parallelism);
            log.info(LogMessageBuilder.buildLogMessage("Cassandra sink cluster builder is ready"));
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            (exp.printstacktrace());
        }
    }
=====================================================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

> I read that flink maintain states internally even no states are implemented explicitly

Some of the built-in operators do implicitly maintain state, such as

- some sources and sinks
- windows
- CEP
- reduce, sum, max, min

---

From the stack trace you've shared, it appears that the checkpoint contains state for a source operator that cannot be restored; presumably your custom source.

If you want to share the code of the custom source it will be easier to diagnose the problem, but I would first look to see if you have properly implemented the `CheckpointedFunction` interface -- in particular, the `initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in my code i am not implementing CheckpointedFunction  interface. I am facing the state backed issue in two places one is at pattern matching module and another one is cassandra sink function where i will write the state of signals to cassandra tables for audit purpose. I am adding code to the question please ignore if any errors i simplified code just to avoid confusion. If you need any more input please let me know. Is there any documentation how to implement CheckpointedFunction ?

Comment: When you got the error during state restore, had you changed the code in some way before attempting to restart the job? Perhaps you are running into the problem described here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#assigning-operator-ids

Comment: we are not changing any code while flink trying to restart the job and i am using uid for each stream in my code as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: any suggestion on above issue?

Comment: I do see things that don't look right -- for example, I don't see that you are storing anything in the broadcast state. Normally you'd call `put` somewhere in `processBroadcastElement`. But I'm not sure what's causing the `BackendBuildingException`.